# Basic Authentication and jQuery/ajax call

Tags: ajax, jquery, odata

I would like to call OData .NET web service that authenticates users via basic authentication.

I use following ajax call:

```
var fullUri = APIUri + "?$format=json";
$.ajax({
    url: fullUri,
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    type: 'GET',
    jsonp: '$callback',
    beforeSend: function setHeader(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', token);
    },
    success: callback,
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(thrownError);
    },
});
```

The results are unusable for me:

- Calls are blocked because of CORS (until I will paste API url and try to load it in chrome). I tried local html file and html file uploaded to the same domain/port, but authentication fails (according to Chrome console).
- Once I enter service URL into chrome address bar, I am asked to provide login name and password by Chrome. If I enter them, they are cached and used even I assign them in beforeSend. How to blocks this behavior?

I've tried a lot of examples how to configure jsonp, headers etc, but did not find working solution yet.

IIS server response header is also configured using "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*".

Answer (score 0):

You can set the HTTP Password and Username in the AJAX Call directly:

```
$.ajax({
    url: fullUri,
    contentType: "application/json",
    username: <login>,
    password: <password>,
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to support CORS:

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;
```

Regarding the call, are you using HTTPS?  Is the certificate valid?

Comment: Is HTTPS required? I do not use it, just HTTP.